# Cannot download On Demand Resources contents after iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, on-demand-resources

After upgrading some of my devices to iOS 10, I am unable to download ODR contents anymore within my app. Devices which still have iOS 9 are still working without a problem.

Does anyone currently suffering from this problem? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: did you fixed your problem ?

Comment: @NicoAD At the time we published the app removing the ODR support. I decided to test it again today out of curiosity, and the problem appears to be fixed right now. I didn't change anything; thus, I am guessing that it was a problem unrelated to our app. I suggest that you should try it again and see if it's fixed now.

Comment: we entered a bug in apple bug reported which was closed at duplicate. still not fixed in the 10.2 beta3 ... @Perex19

Comment: talked to a guy today who has the same problem in his game. (he is able to reproduce it in a test app) . Seriously apple ?

Comment: I am very unsatisfied with ODR so far, I constantly get problems to fix especially when they release new ios versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged an Apple Developer Technical Support Issue (DTI) on this as I could not find anything that could fix the issue.  After a lot of back and forth I got this from them:

*In iOS 9, the ODR was handled by the OnDemandD daemon inside the OS. However in iOS 10, we switched ODR to now be handled under the AppStoreD daemon. There were some issues that arose from this transistion, including this specific issue. Also, this issue was on our side of the table, so it’s nothing you or your users did.
I cannot get into the details of the issue, because I honestly don’t know what they changed, but as far as I know, it is stemmed from the daemon transistion above.*

Now that iOS 10.2 is out, and will be updating across the iOS fleet, hopefully we'll see and end to this issue.  In the meantime my game has been getting bad reviews and feedback from players experiencing a black screen instead of our game levels.  :-(

Comment: It is sad to learn this but at least we know that the problem is not in our apps. I hope that this gets fixed soon.

Comment: it is amazing how they hide stuff from developers and someone has to pay money in some cases to get the answer. This is why I stopped using ODR a long time ago. This thing never worked as expected since release 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating some devices to iOS 10.

I solved it by setting the **loadingPriority** of the **NSBundleResourceRequest** to 1.

Comment: we have a similar issue, setting loadingPrority to 1 don't fix the issue for us.